# Will I receive a second copy of Dishonored in my Steam inventory, if I pre-order Dishonored 2 as a gift, and add it to my library that way?

Tags: steam, pc, dishonored

If you attempt to purchase Dishonored 2 using 'Purchase for myself' it says:

"you will not receive an extra copy of: Dishonored"

Will I still receive the Dishonored definitive edition for myself and an extra copy of Dishonored for my Steam gift inventory, if I pre-order Dishonored 2?

Answer (score 5):

I own the original dishonored and all dlc contents including "definitive edition".

When I go as far to shopping cart check out. It comes up with a message saying this.

```
According to our records, you already own one or more of the items included in your cart.

If purchasing for yourself, you will not receive an extra copy of:
Dishonored
Dishonored: Dunwall City Trials
Dishonored - The Knife of Dunwall
Dishonored - Void Walker Arsenal
Dishonored: The Brigmore Witches
Would you still like to continue with your purchase?
```

Which meant pretty much NO second game (regardless of if you already own one or not) to give out period. This is pretty much normal for pre-order offers like this.

Basically if you don't have it already. It will get add to your account directly. You will not have a chance to gift it to someone else if purchasing for yourself.

I don't know about purchase as a gift for someone else as I have not done it with a pre-order attached. But I assume both dishonored 2 and dishonored definitive edition will be both gift at the same time.

Comment: Confirm this + a nice aspect with the gifting. Someone should try this out and post his/her experiences.

Comment: Note that if like me you own dishonoured but not it's DLC you will still get the dlc when you enter a dishonoured 2 code that has the offer

Answer (score 0):

Steam has a FAQ regarding extra copies found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656):

The relevant piece of information regarding Dishonored is the following question:

> **Q: Do all duplicate purchases on Steam work this way?**
>
> No. This special offer only applies to games or game packages listed
>   above.

In short, only specific Value titles give you extra giftable copies if you already own some of the games in the bundle.  In every bundled purchase I have ever made, all duplicate copies of the game from the bundle, regardless of source (various Bundle deals, Steam packages, etc), will disappear.

The only exception will be a Bundle that gives you separate keys per game.  You can then just give the key for that specific game to someone else.  Keys that activate multiple games will not give you giftable copies.

Answer (score 0):

The "If you already have it you will not receive an extra copy." also applies to the physical version of the game if you pre-order the collectors edition, as you have to use the one code that's involved with it to receive the Imperial Assassin's pack for Dishonored 2.

Theoretically, you could pass on the code if you're not fussed about having the extra content for yourself.